# To get the Data in required JSON format

Tags: c#, json, json.net

My code for the object is as follows,

```
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer jSearializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
List<object> modified_listofstrings = new List<object>();
List<string> p_Name = new List<string>();
List<float> Data = new List<float>();
List<string> s_Name = new List<string>();
List<float> p_Value = new List<float>();


var obj1=new{
       Data=p_Value
            };
var obj2 = new
            {
        Series=obj1,
            };
 modified_listofstrings.Add(obj1);
jSearializer.Serialize(modified_listofstrings);
```

and output I get is as below,

```
[{"Series":{"Data":[14,14,14,14,18,18,18,18,17,15,13,12]}}]
```

but I want output as in below format,

```
"Series" : [ { "Data" : [14,14,14,14,18,18,18,18,17,15,13,12,""] } ],
```

since I want to use the Values as series.Data... any help will be greatly appreciated,

Comment: modified_listofstrings has List type, so it always has been serialized as array. But you may serialize only first element of modified_listofstrings - jSearializer.Serialize(modified_listofstrings[0]); and get exactly what you want.

Comment: No..actually I don't have issue wit List type since I am going to store many values together, above I have just pasted one example what my list is going to contain, what I want is [] bracket before and after Data and last value as shown above.

Comment: in this case you have just change obj1 property creating like this: var obj1=new[] { new { Data = p_Value } }; 
 Or change obj2 like this: var obj2 = new { Series = new[] { obj1 } };
I hope this helps.

Comment: @DmytroRudenko... It helped me...Thanks a lottt..can you please write it as again as an answer so that I can select it as an answer...Thank you once again....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modified_listofstrings has List type, so it always has been serialized as array. But you may serialize only first element of modified_listofstrings -

```
jSearializer.Serialize(modified_listofstrings[0]);
```

and get exactly what you want.

or another answer. just change obj1 property creating like this:

```
var obj1=new[] { 
    new { Data = p_Value } 
};
```

Or change obj2 like this:

```
var obj2 = new 
{ 
    Series = new[] { obj1 } 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to have your modified_listofstrings as an object and not a List. Unless you want it to be a list ofcourse. If so do a jSearializer.Serialize(modified_listofstrings[0]) as @Dmytro Rudenko suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Try thinking of json to convert in form of csharp classes..
this will avoid problems

from  http://json2csharp.com/

```
public class Series
{
    public List<object> Data { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public List<Series> Series { get; set; }
}
```

now add items to collection and serialize object .. this is right approach when you serialize and deserialize object.